# Generate the faces of a 3D object given its points and edges

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, face, 3d-rendering

I have a 3D wire-frame consisting of 3D points and edges. How do I go about identifying sets of vertices forming a face of the 3D object?

I am using `QT` and want to render a 3D object given its point set and edge set. The best I have been able to do is given three points forming a triangular face, I am able to render it in 3D. But how to do the same given more points and edges? Or, alternatively, how to break down the set in sets of 3 points forming a triangular face?

Comment: Are you talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux polygon triangulation will come after recognising the faces. But first, how to recognise the faces, which are essentially planar cycles in the 3D graph.

Comment: Ok, I see. So from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh what kind of vertices-edges representation do you have?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I have 3D points as (x,y,z) array and edges as (point1, point2).
I want to derive the (triangular) faces using this information so that I can render the object using QT.

Comment: So, you have your basic VV mesh, no faces, and want to get faces and triangulate them and send them to some 3D display tool, right? Mmm... I would look at openmesh.org and read Smith dissertation http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/smithco.dis2006.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. :)

Comment: And CGAL might have something useful https://www.cgal.org/

Answer (score 0):

- Just take your first edge and its vertices (V1 and V2).
- Find all edges that use V2 - their second vertices are your potential V3's.
- For each potential V3 check if you have edge V1-V3 - if so, then you've found a triangle V1-V2-V3. For most meshes you should have one or two such triangles. When you're adding a new triangle always check if wasn't found already.
- Do the same for edges that use V1.
- Take next edge and repeat.

Depending on your exact data, edge directions, etc. it may need slight modifications but you should get the point.